# .NET decimal.ToString(format) in Javascript

Tags: .net, javascript, decimal

I have a string (€#,###.00) which works fine with aDecimal.ToString("€#,###.00") in .NET, i wonder if anyone knows how this could be achieved with javascript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's `.toLocaleString()`, but unfortunately the specification defines this as "implementation dependant" - I hate when they do that.  Thus, it behaves differently in different browsers:

```
var val = 1000000;

alert(val.toLocaleString())
// -> IE: "1,000,000.00"
// -> Firefox: "1,000,000"
// -> Chrome, Opera, Safari: "1000000" (i know, it's the same as toString()!)
```

So you can see it can't be relied upon because the ECMA team were too lazy to properly define it.  Internet Explorer does the best job of formatting it as a currency.  You're better off with your own or [someone else](http://javascript.internet.com/forms/currency-format.html)'s implementation.

---

or [mine](http://jsfiddle.net/R4DKn/):

```
(function (old) {
    var dec = 0.12 .toLocaleString().charAt(1),
        tho = dec === "." ? "," : ".";

    if (1000 .toLocaleString() !== "1,000.00") {
        Number.prototype.toLocaleString = function () {
           var f = this.toFixed(2).slice(-2); 
           return this.toFixed(2).slice(0,-3).replace(/(?=(?!^)(?:\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, tho) + dec + f;
        }
    }
})(Number.prototype.toLocaleString);
```

Tested in IE, Firefox, Safari, Chrome and Opera in my own locale only (en-GB).

Comment: Thanks, but yea doesn't help much :p

Comment: @Mikael: you're right, it wasn't very helpful.  I added my own solution to the post, tested in Firefox, IE, Opera, Chrome and Safari.

Answer (score 1):

I think [jQuery Globalization plugin](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/06/10/jquery-globalization-plugin-from-microsoft.aspx) gets close

Comment: yea im using that for when i have a locale, but in some cases i don't and i only have that formatting string

Comment: And what would output would you expect from the formatting string without the locale?

Comment: well in this case i have Euro, it's hard to tie Euro to a single locale, that's why i want to be able to specify a format for the currency Euro, inputting 1200.5 with the format €#,###.00 should obviously output €1,200.50

I guess i have to attempt to write my own function since it doesn't seem to exist.

Comment: You could create your own "Europe" locale in the globalization plugin.

Comment: Yea that's what i have atm, the problem is just that it might be other custom formats in the future. But i guess ill have to deal with them later.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same Problem once and I decided to go with a little overengineered (maybe stupid) way: I wrote a service who accepted a decimal as parameter and gave me a formatted string back. The main Problem was, that I didnt know which culture the User was using in Javascript.

Comment: in my case it'd be too much to do ajax calls for every format instance