# How to format numbers using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, localization

I want to format number using javascript as below:

```
10.00=10,00 
1,000.00=1.000,00
```

Comment: You mean this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/51564/javascript-culture-sensitive-currency-formatting

Comment: Possible duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4843691/javascript-regex-replacing-the-last-dot-for-a-comma

Comment: @Shadow Wizard : No this is not same. I could not get the result for 1,50,000.00 as 1.50.000,00 using that script..

Comment: So you might have to write your own "format" function using string manipulation.

Answer (score 19):

Every browser supports `Number.prototype.toLocaleString()`, a method intended to return a localized string from a number.  However, the specification defines it as follows:

> Produces a string value that represents the value of the Number formatted according to the conventions of the host environment's current locale. This function is *implementation-dependent*, and it is permissible, but not encouraged, for it to return the same thing as `toString`.

Implementation-dependant means that it's up to the vendor how the result will look, and results in interoperability issues.

**Internet Explorer** (IE 5.5 to IE 9) comes closest to what you want and formats the number in a currency style - thousands separator and fixed at 2 decimal places.

**Firefox** (2+) formats the number with a thousands separator and decimal places but only if applicable.

**Opera, Chrome & Safari** output the same as `toString()` -- no thousands separator, decimal place only if required.

## Solution

I came up with the following code (based on [an old answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3044056/net-decimal-tostringformat-in-javascript/3044175#3044175)) to try and normalize the results to work like Internet Explorer's method:

```
(function (old) {
    var dec = 0.12 .toLocaleString().charAt(1),
        tho = dec === "." ? "," : ".";

    if (1000 .toLocaleString() !== "1,000.00") {
        Number.prototype.toLocaleString = function () {
           var neg = this < 0,
               f = this.toFixed(2).slice(+neg);

           return (neg ? "-" : "") 
                  + f.slice(0,-3).replace(/(?=(?!^)(?:\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, tho) 
                  + dec + f.slice(-2);
        }
    }
})(Number.prototype.toLocaleString);
```

This will use the browser's built-in localization if it's available, whilst gracefully degrading to the browser's default locale in other cases.

**Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/R4DKn/49/**

Comment: I'm voting for this solution, since it supports proper localization. Some of us are using decimal comma instead of dot :-)

Comment: +1 - just a warning: needs to be fixed to deal properly with negative numbers. currently -100 returns -,100.00 for example.

Comment: just to be clear. to see the issue you'll need to call (-100).toLocaleString()

Comment: @PatrickKlug: Thanks for pointing it out, I didn't originally consider negatives and didn't test them.  I've fixed it now :-)

Comment: What about converting the localized number back?

Comment: if you're planning to run unittests in node.js you will need to load the intl package

Answer (score 9):

I know this solution using NumberFormat but it is necessary to convert the values to string.
https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/NumberFormat

```
// Remove commas
number = "10,000.00".replace(/,/g, '');

// Create a NumberFormat type object
var formatter = new Intl.NumberFormat('de-DE', {
    minimumFractionDigits: 2
}); 

// Apply format
console.log(formatter.format(number));

output:10.000,00
```

Answer (score 1):

Javascript doesn't provide this functionality itself, but there are a number of third-party functions around which can do what you want.

Note, whichever method you use, you should be careful to only use the resulting string for display purposes -- it won't be a valid number value in Javascript after you've converted the decimal point to a comma.

The quickest solution I can offer is to use the `number_format()` function written by the phpJS people. They've implemented Javascript versions of a load of commonly-used PHP functions, including `number_format()`, and this function will do exactly what you want.

See the link here: http://phpjs.org/functions/number_format

I wouldn't bother about taking the whole phpJS library (a lot of it is of questionable value anyway), but just grab the 20-odd line function shown on the page linked above and paste it into your app.

If you want a more flexible solution, there are a number of JS functions around which simulate the `printf()` function from C. There is already a good question on SO covers this. See here: [JavaScript equivalent to printf/string.format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/610406/javascript-printf-string-format)

Hope that helps.