# Number format with comma and decimal points

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have tried using `Number(x).toLocaleString()`, but this only gives me **10,000**.

When I use `parseFloat(row.profit).toFixed(2)` it gives me **10000.00**. I tried combining `parseFloat(Number(row.profit)toLocaleString()).toFixed(2)` But not give me the desired output which should be **10,000.00**. 
How can I achieve this?

Comment: look at the specs for toLocaleString. `minimumFractionDigits` is an option you can set.

Comment: OK, so you didn't ask about money, but if you ignore the dollar sign the linked duplicate is asking the same thing about the commas and decimals, and e.g., [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/149099/615754) does it with a fairly short function.

Comment: Consider the answers to [*How to format numbers using JavaScript?*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5882994/how-to-format-numbers-using-javascript/5884019#5884019), which uses *toLocaleString* to determine whether to use "," for thousands and "." for decimal or *vice versa*.

Comment: @nnnnnn the link answer is delete please check

Comment: @guradio - Sorry, I accidentally double-pasted the URL in my link. Have edited my previous comment to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a quick hack by testing if `.` is present in your locale string or not :

```js
function localeFormat(x) {
  var num = Number(x).toLocaleString();
  if (num.indexOf("/.") > 0) {
    num += ".00";
  }else{
    var n = parseFloat(x).toFixed(2).toString();  
    num = Number(n).toLocaleString();
  }
  return num;
}
var strs = ["10000", "10000.45", "10000.45768"];
for(var i = 0; i < strs.length; i++){
  console.log(strs[i] + " -> " + localeFormat(strs[i]));
}
```