# Change numeric format

Tags: jquery, numbers, numeric

I'm using jquery and I need to switch the order of commas and dots in all numbers.

For example:

120,400.50 -> 120.400,50

Comma for decimals and dot for the rest.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to format numbers using JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5882994/how-to-format-numbers-using-javascript)

Comment: Did you try anything? Google?

Comment: @HectorLandete Did you check the answer?

Answer (score 3):

If you want to format the number - you can use the above comment by @Conduit (the possible duplicate).

If you have a known string (with commas and dots) and you want to replace them, you can use a regex with a replacement function:

```js
s = '120,400.50'
console.log(s.replace(/([\.,])/g, a => { return a === '.' ? ',' : '.'} ))
```